# Creating a moduleNameMapper for ts-jest import of ts-gaussian?

Tags: angular, typescript, jestjs, ts-jest, angular-package-format

I've created a [demo for this issue here](https://github.com/fireflysemantics/tsgaussian-demo/tree/test-passing/projects/demo).

The `fail` branch has a test that tries to import `ts-gaussian` like this:

```
import { Gaussian } from 'ts-gaussian';
const distribution = new Gaussian(0, 1);
test("gaussian", ()=>{
    expect(true).toBeTruthy()
} )
```

And this test fails because `ts-jest` does not know how to resolve the `ts-gaussian` module.

I asked about this on the `ts-jest` repository and was told that it's because a `moduleNameMapper` has to be created for the import.

Does anyone know how to do this for this project?

The steps for cloning and running the test are:

```
git clone git@github.com:fireflysemantics/tsgaussian-demo.git tsgauss

cd tsgauss

git switch fail
npm i
npm test
```

The result is:

```
ts-jest[config] (WARN) message TS151001: If you have issues related to imports, you should consider setting `esModuleInterop` to `true` in your TypeScript configuration file (usually `tsconfig.json`). See https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/typescript/2018/01/31/announcing-typescript-2-7/#easier-ecmascript-module-interoperability for more information.
 FAIL  src/lib/demo.spec.ts
  ● Test suite failed to run

    Cannot find module 'ts-gaussian' from 'src/lib/demo.spec.ts'

    > 1 | import { Gaussian } from 'ts-gaussian';
        | ^
      2 | const distribution = new Gaussian(0, 1);
      3 | test("gaussian", ()=>{
      4 |     expect(true).toBeTruthy()

      at Resolver.resolveModule (../../node_modules/jest-resolve/build/resolver.js:322:11)
      at Object.<anonymous> (src/lib/demo.spec.ts:1:1)

Test Suites: 1 failed, 1 total
Tests:       0 total
Snapshots:   0 total
Time:        2.158 s
Ran all test suites.
```

Comment: Install `ts-gaussian` package by this command `npm i ts-gaussian`

Comment: @hoangdv if you clone the repository you will see that the `ts-gaussian` dependency is already included.  So `npm i` will install it and when the jest test is ran, it produces the error ...

Comment: https://github.com/fireflysemantics/tsgaussian-demo/blob/fail/projects/demo/package.json , you executed the command in `demo` directory or root project directory?

Comment: It needs to be executed in the project root directory because the Angular Package Format library project knows how to pull dependencies from the root directory ...